# Styling differences in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

I am working on a Wordpress menu and there are styling differences in the logo on the menu.

For chrome everything seems to work fine. The menu looks like this:

[image]

However, in Firefox the menu looks like this:

[image]

I am not sure where the styling difference is coming from. 
Does anyone have any idea of how to fix this? I've tried adding custom css but I can't seem to get both browsers to comply.

Thank you.

```
<div class="logo left">
   <a href="http://www.data-profits.com/" rel="home">
   <img alt="" src="http://www.data-profits.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/dataProfitsLogoGlow-300x691.png">
   </a>
 </div>
```

The Relevant css is:

```
header.top-head .logo {
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
-ms-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
display: table;
height: 90px;
float: left;
}
.stickyHeader .logo {
   transform: scale(0.8);
   -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
   -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
   height: 60px !important;
  }
.head-7 .logo {
  height: 70px !important;
}
.logo.left {
  position: absolute;
}
.left {
   float: left !important;
 }
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a link or the snippet of the codes so people could test it?

Comment: http://www.data-profits.com thank you

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: With the amount of code you've given now, I can't reproduce the problem of the logo being in different positions. https://jsfiddle.net/7x2ycjyy/